# Nginx doesn't redirect if url has .html extension

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm trying to serve a maintenance page. So I gave `try_files` a try and always serve `maintenance.html`.

It works well if url is like app.amazing.com or anything like `app.amazing.com/[a-z0-9]*` but as soon as there's a html extension, Nginx tries to serve this very file (exemple : `app.amazing.com/test.html`) and returns a 404 if it doesn't exist.

```
server {
    listen [::]:443;
    listen 443;

    server_name app.amazing.com;
    root /var/www/front/public;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/expires.conf;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files /maintenance.html =404;
    }
}
```

I also tried a rewrite like that:

```
location / {
        rewrite (.*) /maintenance.html break;
}
```

I even tried this [if-based solution](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/pro-tip-redirecting-custom-nginx-maintenance-page/), but nothing seems to work. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: tested and working**

```
server {
    listen [::]:443;
    listen 443;

    server_name app.amazing.com;
    root /var/www/front/public;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/expires.conf;

    charset utf-8;

    set $maintenance on;
    if ($uri ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|html)(\?[0-9]+)? ) {
        set $maintenance off;
    }
    if ($maintenance = on) {
        return 503;
    }
    error_page 503 @maintenance;
    location @maintenance {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
    }   
    location / {
        # here hoes your usual location / rules
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

Please change the 404 code to 503, like this:

```
server {
    listen [::]:443;
    listen 443;

    server_name app.amazing.com;
    root /var/www/front/public;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/expires.conf;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

404 = NOT FOUND

**UPDATE:**
302 = TEMPORARY REDIRECT

Comment: 503 is not redirect. 3XX should be used instead.

Comment: I thought that `=404` was just in case `maintenance.html` didn't exist. But for a redirect, it's more accurate. Anyways, that doesn't change the fact that typing `app.amazing.com/test.html` still returns a 404.